# Want dark color of button placed on transparent layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiview-hierarchy

I have one transparent layer on my controller with imageview on it. Now when I put the button with image it shows transparency. Though I make the alpha set to 1 on button and I also know the button are always transparent but I have to nil buttons transparency. I couldn't find solution.

Do answer as soon as possible..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which portion, you want to make transparent ?

Comment: I want that my button won't show any transparency when placed on transparent view

Answer (score 0):

Change button background colour to white colour in following manner.

```
objButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: but i want my button to be of color gray

Comment: Simply change the button background color.. default to gray..